# Jquery/JS : replace a row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace one whole row using JQuery but seems not working ( the row is NOT being replaced). Here is the link to the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/s2kwb/

JavaScript:

```
$("td.99999").first().parent().next().replaceWith("<tr><td >category 3</td>
<td >2222</td>
<td >something 22</td>
<td >something 22</td>
<td >$3,433</td>
<td >$300</td>
<td >$3,733</td>
<td >$349</td>
<td >$4,082</td>
</tr>");​
```

Html:

```
<table border="1">
<tr >
  <th>category</th>
  <th>rank</th>
  <th>priority</th>
  <th>contact</th>
  <th>price</th>
  <th>tax</th>
  <th>total price</th>
  <th>shipping</th>
  <th>Net payment</th>
</tr>
<tr class="displaytagOddRow">
  <td class="99999">category 1</td>
  <td class="99999">99999</td>
  <td class="99999">something</td>
  <td class="99999">something</td>
  <td class="99999 alignRight">$3,433</td>
  <td class="99999 alignRight">$300</td>
  <td class="99999 alignRight">$3,733</td>
  <td class="99999 alignRight">$349</td>
  <td class="99999 alignRight">$4,082</td>
</tr>
<tr class="displaytagOddRow" style="Background-color:Red">
  <td class="3333">category 2</td>
  <td class="3333">3333</td>
  <td class="3333">something</td>
  <td class="3333">something</td>
  <td class="3333 alignRight">$3,433</td>
  <td class="3333 alignRight">$300</td>
  <td class="3333 alignRight">$3,733</td>
  <td class="3333 alignRight">$349</td>
  <td class="3333 alignRight">$4,082</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminate the string for every line. See also the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2kwb/3/).

```
$("td.99999").first().parent().next().replaceWith("<tr><td >category 3</td>" +
    "<td >2222</td>" +
    "<td >something 22</td>" +
    "<td >something 22</td>" +
    "<td >$3,433</td>" +
    "<td >$300</td>" +
    "<td >$3,733</td>" +
    "<td >$349</td>" +
    "<td >$4,082</td>" +
    "</tr>");​
```

---

The [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Multiline_string_literals) recommends this string concatenation and advises against multiline strings with the alternative backslash line breaks.

> whitespace after the slash will result in tricky errors

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the errors in your fiddle and adding jQuery as a reference made it work:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2kwb/6/)

Your string was not proper string literal. The console in the browser debug tool also stated that:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal [Break On This Error]
>
> $("td.99999").first().parent().next().replaceWith("category
>   3

Fixed script:

```
$("td.99999").first().parent().next().replaceWith("<tr><td >category 3</td><td >2222</td><td >something 22</td><td >something 22</td><td >$3,433</td><td >$300</td><td >$3,733</td><td >$349</td><td >$4,082</td></tr>");
```

Comment: **This works too.thank you.Realized that the newline was the issue**